How to counter calcium buildup
I am noticing that my toilet tank and the sinks in my home are having issues with calcium buildup. What can I do to help combat this?

There are retail and homemade calcium cleaners/removers.  For long term fix, you would be looking at water filters/softeners.

Clean it with vinegar or a calcium cleaning product.
A whole-house water softener will prevent the buildup.

Some people say,  one or more strong magnet(s) at the water tube(s) help to avoid/slow down the calcium build ups.
There seems to be no scientific research with systematic testing.
Some people deny any effect.
But strong magnets can be available for free at the next recycling yard.
The magnets from  loudspeakers, electric motors, seals of refrigerator doors (coiled around pipes/tubes) and other parts can be used to check if the magnetic forces do change the water and/or calcium compositions in a way that decreases the probability of depositions on surfaces like sinks and tubes.
And even simple things concerning water seemed still to be not completely clear  just until a few years ago, see the Mpemba effect - hot water freezes quicker than cold water. 5 years ago, there were still different speculations/explanations of the Mpemba effect on the English, French and German Wikipedia sites.
The recycled/upcycled magnet method is completely free of costs, free of any chemicals and may contribute to more knowledge concerning this effect (or non- existing effect).
On the other side, commercial water softeners do need much maintenance, some users complain of unusual water smell.
And they cost a lot, and mostly need professionals for installing.
Installing magnets at the outside surface of water pipes/tubes does not need any professionals and is a matter of seconds/minutes without any risk of interfering with hygienic standards.
And they can be removed in a few seconds as well.

Calcium is not magnetic. Magnets are not magic. They will do no harm except to your wallet, but they will do no good either.

@keshlam 1. Flowing water molecules that contain OH- Ions plus Calcium components that may be also ionized do react on magnetic forces. 2. The magnets from old loudspeakers or motors in the recycling yard are normally free.

"do react" how? There isn't VA lasting change, so the best result one might hope for would be to precipitate the calcium at that point ... Which would create a build-up that would eventually start to choke the pipe. That does not seem a good solution (oun not intended). In any case, this should be something easily testable, and should have solid proof if it works rather than being rumor and fringe manufacturers. Sorry, I remain skeptical that this works any better than the magnets claimed to improve gasoline.

@keshlam No, a filtering/precipitating is not intended/happening - just the contrary.
The complex solution of water and minerals and ions  could be influenced by the magnetic forces in such a way that the surface tensions/surface energy levels/surface areas etc. would be changed to lower the probability of the minerals to build a layer on the  downstream surfaces.
Working or not?
With free magnets from recycling yards it is worth a trial: no cost, little time needed, no chemicals, no hygienic risk, no opening of the water net.
In the worst case it does not work. But no lost of money.

@keshlam Compare washing pouders/washing solutions, where the dirt which has been just separated from the clothes is surrounded by special ions (ions with one  hydrophobic end and another  non- hydrophobic end) in order to avoid a (re-) settling on the clothes/dishes and washing machines and drainage tubes.

That's a chemical effect. Magnets will not cause anything similar.

@keshlam Every chemical effect - without exemption - is based on electro- magnetic forces.
And magnets can influence the very complex composition of water with minerals/mineral - OH - clusters. A strong magnet next to the water coming out of a tap can even "bend" the water flow.
And the physics of surfaces is very complex, the more if that many substances are involved.
It is not clear if magnets do have a positive effect on the deposits or not.
But why not test it for free without any risk?

You wanna waste your time on misunderstood science, be my guest.
